# get partition ((N-1)-dimensional instance of the N-dimensional array) of a multidimensional array with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get a 2d array from a 3d array. Let's say I have a double 3d array A3 of dimension [10,10,10]
I need to get a 2d array A2 = A3[:,5,:], i.e. where the index of the second dimension is equal to e.g. 5.

If I want to get the partition (for instance of the kind A1=A2[2,:]) of 2d array A2 (i.e. 1d instance of 2d array) I can do this (the index of the 1-st dimensional is set e.g. to 2):

```
double[] A1 = Enumerable.Range(0,A2.Length).Select(x=>A2[2,x]).ToArray();
```

How can I do it going from 3 to 2 (or generally from N to N-1) dimensions?

**Edit**. Example input:

```
double[,,] A3 = new double[2,3,4]{
            {
                {4,3,2,1},
                {5,4,3,2},
                {6,5,4,3}
            },
            {
                {1,2,3,4},
                {2,3,4,5},
                {3,4,5,6}
            }
        };
```

The result array A2=A3[:,1,:] must have the following inside: { {5,4,3,2},{2,3,4,5} }

Comment: Are your partitions of equal size, or is it jagged?

Comment: Why do you need Linq? It's going to be loads easier just writing loops to do it (probably run faster too). Just write an extension method to do it, and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: dimensions are not equal, it could be [2,17,5];  one can always write a loop or function instead of LINQ. besides, assume that knowing how to do this task I can easily extend this approach to other multidimensional objects

Answer (score 1):

LINQ in general doesn't play too well with multi-dimensional arrays.  The operations are inherently single dimensional.  It plays much better with nested single dimensional arrays, so if you wanted to return a jagged array of depth two, i.e. a `double[][]` rather than a `double[,]` LINQ is a more appropriate tool.

```
public static T[][] GetPlane<T>(T[, ,] source, int secondDimensionValue)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetLength(0))
        .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetLength(2))
            .Select(j => source[i, secondDimensionValue, j])
            .ToArray())
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was asking about the rank lengths - if they were all equal, you could mangle a SelectMany + offset calcs in there

Comment: @JerKimball Note that even if the lengths of the dimensions aren't equal it's not a jagged array.  A jagged array is were the length of a single dimension isn't constant, which isn't *possible* with a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: it works, thanks, could you tell me please how can I get it as a [,] array and not a ("jagged"?) [][] array?

Comment: @MaxLi By far the easiest way would be to scrap LINQ entirely and just use regular loops.  Create the multi-dimensional array of the appropriate size at the start, have a double `for` loop going through the two dimensions that change, and then set the relevant value of the array in the body of the loop.

Comment: @Servy using loops is trivial. the question is how to get it using linq whatever the motivation behind it )

Comment: @MaxLi And you're not going to generate a multi-dimensional array using LINQ, so given a choice between returning a multi-dimensional array without linq and a jagged array with LINQ, I choose the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for 3->2:

```cs
static T[][] Collapse<T>(T[][][] array, int y)
{
  return
    Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length).Select(x =>
      Enumerable.Range(0, array[x][y].Length).Select(z =>
        array[x][y][z]
      ).ToArray()
   ).ToArray();
}
```

It should be fairly obvious how to extend this pattern to higher dimensional problems.

***Edit:***

This extends to multidimensional arrays in the expected manner. If you're interested in returning a multidimensional array (as opposed to a jagged array), LINQ probably isn't the tool that you want to use to solve this problem as it provides no obvious or intuitive methods for handling multidimensional array creation.

If you really want the multidimensional array as output, I've included a sample "deburr" implementation that should collapse it back to a multidimensional (non-jagged) array.

```cs
static T[][] Collapse<T>(T[,,] array, int y)
{
  return
    Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0)).Select(x =>
      Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(2)).Select(z =>
        array[x,y,z]
      ).ToArray()
    ).ToArray();
}

static T[,] Deburr<T>(T[][] jagged)
{
  T[,] mArray = new T[jagged.Length, jagged.Max(array => array.Length)];

  foreach (int row in Enumerable.Range(0, jagged.Length))
    foreach (int col in Enumerable.Range(0, jagged[row].Length))
      mArray[row, col] = jagged[row][col];

  return mArray;
}
```

Comment: could you please put the example input from the edit of the post into your function? I changed [][][] to [,,] etc, but still don't get it running

Comment: I've updated the answer to include multidimensional examples.